# MongoDB date string sorting in varies format

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pymongo

Due to business requirement, I have to sort the records base on a date field which stores value as date string in 2 formats.

1. Yyyy-Mm-Dd
2. Yyyy-Mm-DdThh:mm:ss+00:00

for example, assume we have 2 records as following:

```
[
    {
        _id: 01
        modified_date: "2023-01-01T01:01:01+00:00"
    },
    {
        _id: 02
        modified_date: "2023-01-02"
    }
]
```

when I run query:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort('modified_date', 1)
```

for ascending order over modified_date, I am expecting to see the records in order of [01, 02], since 2023-01-01T01:01:01+00:00 is earlier than 2023-01-02.

However, the actual result is [02, 01] and it seems like the sort() of mongodb is considering "2023-01-02" is shorting than "2023-01-01:01:01:01+00:00" which has higher priority than comparing the actual values (unlike python string sorting logic, using python to sort above 2 date string, "2023-01-01:01:01:01+00:00" is smaller than "2023-01-02")

I need help with this to see if anyone know how to correctly tell mongodb to sort the date string meanfully.

**NOTE**: I only want to use sort() over cursor object (which is returned by db.collection.find()). I already tried aggregation + $addField + $sort. But the performance is way worse compare to find() + sort() when millions of records are evaluated.